# Problem Exporting Maps from Google Spreadsheets

Tags: html, xml, google-sheets-api, html-imports

I have been creating maps and am having problems exporting from Google spreadsheets.

I have a `.ts` file:

```
import type { YMapLocationRequest, BehaviorType, LngLat } from "@yandex/ymaps3-types";
CONST CORDS = //here will be the cords from google spreadsheets 
export const LOCATION: YMapLocationRequest = {
  center: [37.623082, 55.75254], // starting position [lng, lat]
  zoom: 9, // starting zoom
};
export const INITIAL_LINE_COORDINATES: LngLat[] = [];
```

I need to export a column from a Google spreadsheet so that the values of each row are separated by a comma and embed them in the row here:

```
export const INITIAL_LINE_COORDINATES: LngLat[] = [CORDS];
```

Comment: You want to query the Google Spreadsheet in a TypeScript (TS) query and then take results and save to a CSV.  See following on how to query Google Spreadsheet in a TS script.  You do not need to use TypeScript.  You can do same in a Powershell script.